# How to test that a base constructor receives right arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, justmock

I'm creating a methodology to write Unit Tests in my company. We are focused on testing one thing each time but in the case of checking that a base constructor receives the right parameters I'm not finding anything else rather than testing the base constructor as well.

Is there a better approach? We are using MSTest together with JustMock and Rhino so extended features are available but anyway I've not find a way. Find an example below:

```
public Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car() : base(4) {};
}

public Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle(int wheelNumber) {};
}
```

I would like to put an expectation on the base constructor parameter as I would do with a normal method.

Thanks

Comment: I realize this is probably just an example, but the number of wheels doesn't seem like something that should be constant. If the base class has the option to specify something then hard coding that in the derived class like you have done breaks the contract of the base class.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: of course you're right. This was an example written while I was doing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect anything about the base constructor.  For your code, I would make sure that `Car` is a vehicle and then check that the default wheelNumber was set properly (and this only if there were a public method for knowing that).

If the constructor for `Car` repeated the code in `Vehicle` involving the `wheelNumber` your test should still pass.  And then when someone refactors the code so that it is done properly the test should still pass.  That way you know that you haven't changed your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can test a base constructor in that manner.

If you are exposing a base property perhaps you test that

Roughly:

```
Assert.AreEqual(car.BaseProperty,4)
```

Or you can test the expected behavior of a public method that acts on the data/variable, another pseudocode:

```
 class Vehicle
 {
    protected int  X{}
    public Vehicle(int x)
    { 
      X= x;
      ++X;
     }
 }
 car = new Car(4);
 Assert.ReturnsFive(car.DoSomething(),5)
```